# SQL set values of one column equals to a output of a function from another column's text

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a list of names stored in `[TempTable]` table with 2 fields, `[ClientName]` and `[NameID]`. `ClientName` is input from another source that contains symbols and I would like to process them into `[NameID]` field after removing for all the special symbols.

Below is the code for removing symbols:

```
 Public Function RemoveSpecial(Str As String) As String
    Dim xChars As String
    Dim I As Long
    xChars = "~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`{}|[]\:;'<>?,./"
    For I = 1 To Len(xChars)
        Str = Replace$(Str, Mid$(xChars, I, 1), "")
    Next
    RemoveSpecial = Str
End Function
```

I was thinking somewhere along the lines of:

`UPDATE [TempTable] SET [NameID] = RemoveSpecial([ClientName])`

However, the SQL does not seem to work. I just end up having the `[]` in `[ClientName]` removed. Is there a way to use the function in the SQL code or do I have to loop through every entry in the table one by one?

Comment: which db you are really using ???'

Comment: my apologies. ms-access.

Comment: What code are you using to evaluate the SQL? Or are you using a saved query?

Comment: Can't replicate the issue. Similar code runs fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it works fine. Maybe you can modify it like below.
I tested in a query designer. How do you run your SQL code (from query designer or from VBA)?

```
UPDATE TempTable SET TempTable.NameID = RemoveSpecial([TempTable]![ClientName]);
```

Simple code in VBA (without error handling):

```
Public Function UpdateName()
    CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE TempTable SET TempTable.NameID = RemoveSpecial([TempTable]![ClientName]);")
End Function
```

I tested in Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the character positions in here and that is probably why it does not work correctly:

```
Str = Replace$(Str, Mid$(xChars, I, 1), "")
```

Try this code:

```
Public Function RemoveAllSpecialCharacters(inString As String) As String
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},-,/,_,;,',?,+,=,.,~,`, ,€"
    Dim newString As String
    Dim Char As Variant
    newString = inString
    For Each Char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
        newString = Replace(newString, Char, "")
    Next
    newString = Replace(newString, ",", "")
    newString = Replace(newString, Chr(13), "")
    newString = Replace(newString, Chr(10), "")
    RemoveAllSpecialCharacters = Trim(newString)
End Function
```